# Transitive injection of CDI bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a REST controller

```
@Path("/greet")
@RequestScoped
public class GreetController {

    @Inject
    private GreeterService greeterService;

    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String greet(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return greeterService.greet(name);
    }
}
```

which uses the GreeterService

```
@RequestScoped
public class GreeterService {

    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter;

    public String greet(String name) {
        return greeter.greet(name);
    }
}
```

The GreeterService itself injects a Interface which has two implementations

```
@RequestScoped
@Hello
public class HelloGreeter implements Greeter {

    @Override
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

and

```
@RequestScoped
@Whazzup
public class WhazzupGreeter implements Greeter {

    @Override
    public String greet(String name) {
        return "Whazzup " + name;
    }
}
```

`@Whazzup` and `@Hello` are simply Qualifiers.

I'm trying to inject the correct implementation of the `Greeter`-Interface into the `GreeterService` based on the Qualifier used in the GreetController.
Is this even possible using CDI?
An easy workaround would of course be to have two `GreeterService`s for each Qualifier but this seems to be a bad idea as the count of `GreeterService`s increases when new Qualifiers are added.

Of course this is just a basic example and the GreeterServcie is unnecessary but I'm not allowed to post my companies code to StackOverflow so I had to implement a simple example which reproduces our architecture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your description seems to somewhat contradict what you say you want to achieve.
By putting a qualifier on an injection point in `GreeterController`, you are saying that you want an implementation of `GreeterService` with given qualifier.
E.g. for `@Inject @Wazzup GreeterService service`, there has to be a bean of type `GreeterService` and with qualifier `@Wazzup`. So the more qualifiers you have will be using for that, the more beans you will need.

Comment: You could also have an "ultimate producer" that creates beans for all injection points of given type and does that bases on inspecting the injection point. From there, you could see what qualifier is used. Is that what you are after? It would still require you too specify a qualifier on `@Inject Greeter greeter;` though.

Comment: What I want is that my ```GreeterService``` chooses the right implementation of ```Greeter``` based on the annotation I provided in the ```GreetController```. I dont know if this is the right way to achieve such behaviour.

Comment: The qualifying annotations at the class-level of ```GreeterService``` and the field ```greeterService``` in the controller are just part of my tries.. I removed them in the original post.
Maybe this makes my intention more clear: **I want to control which implementation of ```Greeter``` will be injected into the ```GreeterService``` based on the controller.**

Comment: I see no qualifiing annotations at the injects. Who should have the responsibility to decide what Greeter should be injected. That one should be able to use the qualifiers.

Comment: If you take a look at the history of the original post you see that I removed the qualifiers at the inject in class ```GreeterController```. I know that I actually have to put the qualifier at the field ```GreeterService#greeter``` but I want to control which ```Greeter``` will be injected from the ```GreeterController``` without having to define a ```HelloGreeterService``` and a ```WhazzupGreeterService```.

Answer (score 0):

To inject a qualified thing, make sure the qualifier appears on the thing and the injection point:

```
@Inject
@Special
private Thing thing;

@Produces
@Special
private Thing makeSpecialThing() {
    return someSpecialThingCreatedOrGottenFromSomewhere;
}
```

From some of your comments earlier, it appears that you already know this and for whatever (possibly valid, possibly not) reason don't really want to do this.

To pick and choose a thing dynamically at runtime, i.e. once your application starts, as it seems like perhaps you want to do, you can use the facilities exposed by `Instance` (I've made the example below deliberately over-verbose for (hopefully) clarity:

```
final Instance<Object> instance = ... // get an Instance, e.g. via CDI.current() or BeanManager.createInstance()
final Instance<Thing> anyAndAllThings = instance.select(Thing.class);
final Instance<Thing> onlyTheSpecialThing = anyAndAllThings.select(new AnnotationLiteral<SpecialThing>() {});
final Thing theSpecialThing = onlyTheSpecialThing.get();
```

This pattern would let you choose whether you wanted your `Hello`-qualified `Greeter` or your `Whazzup`-qualified `Greeter` at any point.

Usually the desire to do this sort of work at runtime rather than startup time is the tip of a larger problematic iceberg but can be valid in some cases.